# Download previous versions of ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

**Where can previous versions of Extjs can be downloaded from ?**

Specifically I would like to get extjs-4.1.1a and btw what is up with the 'a' is this different from extjs-4.1.1?

Comment: "a" means it contained minor changes: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246386-In-release-version-what-a-stands-for&p=900938

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From this repos:

https://github.com/probonogeek/extjs/commits/master
https://github.com/bjornharrtell/extjs/commits/master

For the missing 4.1.3 here is another repo: 
https://github.com/zenoss/zenoss-extjs/blob/master/ext-4.1.3.zip?raw=true

Took from:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?291411-where-i-can-download-the-old-version-of-extjs

Comment: How do I use the older versions of ExtJS at bjornharrtell git repo? I forked and synced to the commit for 5.0.1 but when I try to use it when generating an app using sencha cmd I get this error: Failed to resolve dependency Ext.app.Application

Comment: I'm sorry that sounds like a question itself, I wouldn't know about it.

Comment: There are some versions missing on both repos.