# ExtJS: How can I download ExtJS 5 non commercial source?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am trying to download ExtJS 5 source javascript file(s) i.e something similar to what we had in Ext JS 4.2 (ext-all-debug-w-comments.js). I am sorry if the questions is irrelavant for stackoverflow or if it's too naive. I could only find the latest version download i.e 6.x.x, but not past major versions. I am wondering if the past versions no more available as non-commercial?

Note: I am trying to download a Windows version.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Note:

The question is not a duplicate as far as I see it. Moreover, the tagged duplicate question provides an external (non Sencha) link to Extjs 4 ... not Extjs 5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download previous versions of ExtJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858560/download-previous-versions-of-extjs)

Comment: ExtJS 5 Release and Opensource download [link](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?286412-ExtJS-5-Release-and-Opensource-download)

Comment: @scebotari66 that questions is about Ext 4 and the answers all point ot some GIT repo. Can you point me to some Sencha owned URL or a CDN probably from where I can download the required versions?

Comment: @Njdhv I have already tried the link ... all of them take you to the latest versions. Did you actually try finding 5.x.x on the link that you gave me? Or am I missing something?

Comment: There are some links like: http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/5.1.0/ or https://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-sencha-ext-js-5-1/ but neither serve my purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the current last GPL version url (http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/ext-6.2.0-gpl.zip), changing the version from the url to 5.1.0 seems to work, resulting in the corresponding url: http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/ext-5.1.0-gpl.zip.

Comment: That's exactly how I figured out the path for a GPL version. Interestingly, the links work only for some specific versions it seems. I am going to accept the answer.

Comment: You need to use https:// protocol now since http:// doesn't work